# Ошибка при получении даты андроид устройства

Tags: java, android-studio, android

Всем привет!Получился вот этот код,требуется получить дату устройства и загрузить определённый xml файл(разметка),получение даты проходит нормально только для числа 1,для числа 2 и 3 не работает,а именно:в самом Андроид Студио число 2 и 3 подчёркивается красным,но билдится нормально,а когда запускаю приложение,приложение игнорирует число 2 и 3,а именно грузит xml которое нужно загрузить для числа 1.

```
    package com.daylang.daylang;

import android.content.Intent;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.animation.Animation;
import android.view.animation.AnimationUtils;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.ImageView;

import java.util.Calendar;

public class Eng_lvl extends AppCompatActivity {

    private int curTime;
    private int someValue;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.eng_lvl);
        Calendar calendar = Calendar.getInstance();
//noinspection WrongConstant
        if (calendar.get(Calendar.DATE) == 1) {
            setContentView(R.layout.eng_lvl);
        }
        if (calendar.get(Calendar.DATE) == 2) {
            setContentView(R.layout.eng_lvl);
        }
        if (calendar.get(Calendar.DATE) == 3) {
            setContentView(R.layout.eng_lvl);
        }
        StartAnimations();
        Button btn = (Button) findViewById(R.id.button5);
        btn.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View view) {
                Intent intent = new Intent(Eng_lvl.this, Eng_learn.class);
                startActivity(intent);
                finish();
            }
        });
        Button btn2 = (Button) findViewById(R.id.buttonask);
        btn.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View view) {
                Intent intent = new Intent(Eng_lvl.this, Ask.class);
                startActivity(intent);
                finish();
            }
        });
    }
    private void StartAnimations() {
        Animation anim = AnimationUtils.loadAnimation(this, R.anim.mytrans);
        anim.reset();
        ImageView iv = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.stars);
        iv.clearAnimation();
        iv.startAnimation(anim);

        anim = AnimationUtils.loadAnimation(this, R.anim.mytrans2);
        anim.reset();
        ImageView l = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.stars2);
        l.clearAnimation();
        l.startAnimation(anim);

        anim = AnimationUtils.loadAnimation(this, R.anim.mytrans5);
        anim.reset();
        ImageView B = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.stars3);
        B.clearAnimation();
        B.startAnimation(anim);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Вы грузите для каждого числа один и тот же xml

Comment: Чёрт!Я даже это не заметил.Спасибо!Не подскажете почему цыфры 2 и 3 краснеют(даже если укажу другие xml)?

Comment: Наведите курсор на 2 или 3 и вы увидите, что в сравнении с днем недели вы должны использовать специальные константы класса Calendar. Однако, остается неясным, почему число 1 не подсвечивается красным, по идее тоже должно

Comment: @P.Ilyin Потому что над выражением с 1 стоит комментарий для подавления соответствующего предупреждения `//noinspection WrongConstant`.

Comment: @eugeneek, что ж, теперь ясно, но кому взбрело в голову так делать? Ответы порождают новые вопросы

Comment: @P.Ilyin Что именно делать? Этот комментарий в данном конкретном месте очень даже нужен. Здесь сравнивается не день недели, а день месяца. Констант в классе `Calendar` на каждый день месяца, естественно нет. Поэтому данное предупреждение разумно подавить. Это было бы неплохо также сделать и для двух оставшихся.